# OpenXML writer usage makes graphics unreadable

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

As I'm writing quite large xlsx files, I'm using `OpenXmlReader` and `OpenXmlWriter` as recommended on this page:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_jones/2010/06/22/writing-large-excel-files-with-the-open-xml-sdk/

What I only do is change formulas inside existing cells and making sure that their value is discarded so that it is recalculated when Excel opens the file.

Here is the function that I'm using:

```
    public void Save(Stream Input, Stream Output)
    {
        Input.Position = 0;
        if (Input != Output)
            Input.CopyTo(Output);

        using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(Output, true))
        {
            WorkbookPart wbPart = document.WorkbookPart;

            // force recalculation as we change formulas
            wbPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties.ForceFullCalculation = true;
            wbPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties.FullCalculationOnLoad = true;

            // store the worksheet parts in a separate list because the loop below
            // adds and removes elements inside wbPart.WorksheetParts
            List<WorksheetPart> originalWsParts = new List<WorksheetPart>();
            foreach (WorksheetPart inputWsPart in wbPart.WorksheetParts)
                originalWsParts.Add(inputWsPart);

            // process all worksheets in the workbook
            foreach (WorksheetPart inputWsPart in originalWsParts)
            {
                string origninalSheetId = wbPart.GetIdOfPart(inputWsPart);

                WorksheetPart replacementWsPart = wbPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                string replacementWsPartId = wbPart.GetIdOfPart(replacementWsPart);

                OpenXmlReader reader = OpenXmlReader.Create(inputWsPart);
                OpenXmlWriter writer = OpenXmlWriter.Create(replacementWsPart);

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    logger.Debug(reader.ElementType.Name);
                    if (reader.ElementType == typeof(Cell) && reader.IsStartElement)
                    {
                        writer.WriteStartElement(reader);

                        // write the cell content, changing the formula and skipping the value
                        while (reader.Read() && !(reader.ElementType == typeof(Cell) && reader.IsEndElement))
                        {
                            if (reader.IsStartElement)
                            {
                                if (reader.ElementType == typeof(CellFormula))
                                {
                                    CellFormula element = reader.LoadCurrentElement() as CellFormula;
                                    element.Text = "SUM(1,2)";
                                    element.CalculateCell = true;
                                    writer.WriteElement(element);
                                }
                                else if (reader.ElementType != typeof(CellValue))
                                {
                                    writer.WriteStartElement(reader);
                                    string elementText = reader.GetText();
                                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(elementText))
                                        writer.WriteString(elementText);
                                }
                            }
                            else if (reader.IsEndElement)
                            {
                                if (reader.ElementType != typeof(CellValue))
                                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                            }
                        }

                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (reader.IsStartElement)
                        {
                            writer.WriteStartElement(reader);
                            string elementText = reader.GetText();
                            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(elementText))
                                writer.WriteString(elementText);
                        }
                        else if (reader.IsEndElement)
                        {
                            writer.WriteEndElement();
                        }
                    }
                }

                reader.Close();
                writer.Close();

                Sheet sheet = wbPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>()
                    .Where(s => s.Id.Value.Equals(origninalSheetId)).First();
                sheet.Id.Value = replacementWsPartId;
                wbPart.DeletePart(inputWsPart);
            }
        }
    }
```

It works quite well on the simplest workbooks, but it creates unreadable files when there are drawings inside sheets in the file.
For instance, if I have a drawings on Sheet1, when Excel opens the saved file, it complains that the file has unreadable parts and shows me the drawings in the list of things it has deleted.

I unzipped the xlsx file and compared the sheetX.xml files, and apart from the added x: prefix, they are the same.

Obviously, I'm missing something but reading the various docs I could find, nothing came to me. I believe there is a reference to the original worksheet part that has not been updated but I don't see any drawings descendant in the workbook.

Any help is most welcome.

**Update**

I looked more closely at the files content and there are two folders missing inside the xl folder: `charts` and `drawings`

So clearly, I'm missing code that would add those into the final archive, but I can't (yet) figure out what code this is.

Answer (score 0):

The above code creates a new `WorksheetPart` inside the loop, when the intention was always to clone the input part.

I thus went looking for a way to clone a worksheet, but there is no `ClonePart()` method on `WorkbookPart`.

Fortunately for me, someone else already had this issue and Brian Jones did a part on his blog about this:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_jones/2009/02/19/how-to-copy-a-worksheet-within-a-workbook/

So, I changed the start of the `using` statement to this:

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(Output, true), tmpDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(new MemoryStream(), document.DocumentType))
{
    WorkbookPart wbPart = document.WorkbookPart;
    WorkbookPart tmpWbPart = tmpDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
```

Then instead of calling `AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>`, I now have the following code:

```
// can't directly clone, so add to the temporary workbook part and then back
// into the working workbook part
WorksheetPart tmpWsPart = tmpWbPart.AddPart(inputWsPart);
WorksheetPart replacementWsPart = wbPart.AddPart(tmpWsPart);
tmpWbPart.DeletePart(tmpWsPart);
tmpWsPart = null;
```

With those changes, I now have my `Drawing` part in the worksheet, the associated folders in the `xlsx` file.
As a result, Excel no longer complains when opening the file and the graphs are all there and updated.